# Prove divergence of the integral without its calculation

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I am looking for an examination of the convergence/divergence of the integral alone without calculation of the integral:
$$\int_0^1 \frac {2x^{1/3}+3\sin^2x} {e^{\tan x^2}-1}dx$$

By and large it seems to me that there is divergence of the integral due to $x=0$. However, how to prove that the integral does not convergence in a clear way?

Comment: What is $g$? Is it a function, a constant (with what sign), etc.?

Comment: Do you mean $\exp(\tan(x^2))$ or $\exp(\tan^2(x))$ when you write $e^{tgx^2}$?

Comment: @user10354138 yes, it means $exp(tan(x^2))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near $x=0$, the denominator is $\sim\tan(x^2)\sim x^2$, and the numerator is $\sim 2x^{1/3}$.  So the integrand is $\sim 2x^{-5/3}$ and hence the integral diverges there, as $\int_0^\varepsilon x^p\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges iff $p>-1$.